# Linq To Entities Join Issues

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

How would you make a join like this with Linq to Entities?

```
var resultA = client.GetFirstList().ToList();                   
var resultB = client.GetSecondList().ToList();

var d = (from b in resultB
         join a in resultA on b.AnICollection.Select(x => x.TypeId) equals a.TypeId 
select b)
```

Comment: What is AnICollection in this case?  A table?

Comment: Yes it would be like b.ItemsTable.Select(x => x.TypeId)   It is a navigation property for b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to query it like the following:

```
from a in context.Customers
join b in context.Orders
on a.CustomerID equals b.CustomerID
join c in context.AnICollection
on b.TypeID equals c.TypeID
select b
```